# How to solve this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to solve the following error?

> CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Helpers' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'NerdDinner' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you missing a `using` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is occurring within a class:

Add using *Nerddiners.Helpers;* to the using statements in your class.

As a short cut, you can place your cursor on the relevant part of your code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and Visual Studio will add it for you.

If the error is occurring within a view:

Add the following to the top of your view (under the inherits definition)

```
<%@ Import Namespace="NerdDinner.Helpers" %>
```

or you can add it to the namespaces section of your projects web.config

```
<namespaces>
...
<add namespace="NerdDinner.Helpers" />
```

If the error is occurring within a *test* class you will need to add a *project reference* to your main NerdDinners project within the add references option of your test project.

Answer (score 0):

not much information given, but [examplanation at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e92xd7b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project in visual studio and click "add reference". Then find the assembly that contains your helpers and add it in.

Failing that you have a programming error